# ng-keyup preventDefault() not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I know it's far from being a best practice, but I really want to understand what's wrong.
I wrote the following code in order to distinguish Enter from shift+Enter, and run the "code" I need:

```
ng-keyup="($event.keyCode == 13 && !$event.shiftKey)
?
  [$event.preventDefault(),
   commentCtrl.edit(comment.id, comment.text),
   comment.edit=false, comment.text]
:
  return"
```

when I press enter, I still get a \n added to my text... :(

Help please!~

Comment: first thing would be move this code to controller function..I think you should do `return false` there instead of only `return`

Comment: I'd rather not move it to a controller, as it will become slower to inject the returned data to the right comment.
I'll try, return false at the end... thanks

Comment: let me know if it works or not?

Comment: could you create a plunkr/fiddle that would help me for more digging

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/vauge5eybG43QuUBsqDS?p=preview

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83674/discussion-between-pankaj-parkar-and-guy-mazuz).

Comment: @Qwertiy, could you help me out pal?

Answer (score 1):

Write this in your html

```
 <input type="text"  ng-keypress="restrictInput($event)" />


 $scope.restrictInput=function(e)
   e.prevenDefault();
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Aha! You've got the "wrong" directive! I just changed mine from ng-keyup to ng-keypress and now $event.preventDefault() works as expected. Hope this helps. I was scratching my head a long time on that.

Comment: But on ng-keypress https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21194098/why-is-my-event-handler-always-one-keystroke-behind-and-how-does-timeout-fix-t

Answer (score 0):

ended up writing a directive that prevents it...

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

angular
    .module('PreventEnterDrc', [])
    .directive('preventEnter', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function(scope, element) {
                element.bind('keydown keypress keyup', function (event) {
                    if(event.keyCode == 13 && !event.shiftKey){
                        event.preventDefault();
                    }
                });
            }
        };
    })
;
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
$event.stopImmediatePropagation()
```

Answer (score -1):

Try the following.

```
ng-keyup="handleKeyup($event);"
```

in your controller,

```
$scope.handleKeyup =  function($event) {
//write your logic here.
}
```

Comment: I don't want to use a controller here, as it will slow the injection of the new text. I'll have to go through all the comments and find the right id... I might consider building a named array [comment_1: object..., comment_2: object]...